# Xqib Hello World not working

Tags: javascript, html, xquery

I am trying implement basics examples of `xquery` but having problem whit Hello World. I have downloaded and placed `mxqueryjs.nocache.js` file correctly, so I don't know where is problem.

**Here is my code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
    <title>HelloWorld</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mxqueryjs/mxqueryjs.nocache.js"></script>
    <script type="application/xquery">
       b:alert("Hello World")
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world page.</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Console output:**

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. 6182B2DC971F7A2C7AEDC4F09F2BAE2D.cache.html:1
(anonymous function) 6182B2DC971F7A2C7AEDC4F09F2BAE2D.cache.html:1
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. 6182B2DC971F7A2C7AEDC4F09F2BAE2D.cache.html:2867
(anonymous function)
```

This should open alert dialog and say Hello World, but it does nothing. Online example is here: [xqib - HelloWorld](http://www.xqib.org/js/HelloWorld.html)

[Xqib home page](http://www.xqib.org/)

Thanks

Comment: Click Ctrl + U to view the source. Copy and replace the source into your current code. See if you still do not get a pop up. If you still don't, it's not your code that's messing you up. Let us know what you get after you try this.

Comment: Did this before and nothing changed, is there any other way to do xquery when html page load?

Comment: Can you open up developers tools in Chrome (Press F12) and go to the Console to see if there is an error?

Comment: Yes there are 2 errors, I had updated question.

Comment: Is your code inside an iframe by any chance?

Comment: All code I used is pasted above in question, so I think the answer is no.

Comment: And I think I will not try and help.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to download this module: `www.xqib.org/js/module.xquery` and import it using a script tag:

```
script type="application/xquery" src="path_to/module.xquery"
```